# Помогите в оптимизации работы с базой данных

Tags: оптимизация, база-данных, postgresql, sphinx, mysql

Помогите в оптимизации работы с базой данных

Есть база товаров, довольно большая и которая  постоянно увеличивается. На данный момент там находиться около 10 миллионов товаров.
Есть товар и есть категория. У товара есть атрибуты название, цена, количество проданных товаров, флаги гарантии, качества, и т д.  Есть свойства товаров характерные только для определенной категории. Свойства товаров имеют вид - 2000:10000 (категория свойства: значение свойства). Некоторые категории свойств и сами свойства могут пересекаться у различных категорий, например бренд. По ним необходимо производить фильтрацию и сортировку и поиск по названию и свойству. Товар может быть привязан к одной или нескольким категориям.

Сначала использовали только mysql, и хранили товары создавая таблицу для каждой категории, так у нас получалось около 6 – 7 тысяч таблиц с товарами, при выборке делали запросы в каждую обедняя при этом запросы оператором UNION. При увеличении товаров, и категорий выборка стала занимать очень много времени и ложит mysql сервер. 
Далее перенесли все товары в одну таблицу. Структура таблиц [следующая](http://clip2net.com/s/5OTUA3).

Таблица с 10 миллионами товаров теперь напрягает mysql, выбор из нее не совсем возможен, не говоря уже о сортировке. - Прикрутили sphinx,  индекс sphinx:

```
sql_query = \

    SELECT \
        ti.item_id, \
        ti.item_id AS iid, \
        crc32(ti.item_nick) AS nick, \
        ti.item_title AS title, \
        ti.item_sold AS sold, \
        ti.item_rating AS rating, \
        ti.item_popular AS popular, \
        ti.item_warranty AS warranty, \
        ROUND(ti.item_price*100, 0) AS price, \
            ti.item_props AS props, \
            COUNT(c.comment_iid) AS comments, \
            GROUP_CONCAT(tcir.category_item_ref_tid) AS tids \
        FROM item AS ti \
    LEFT JOIN comment AS c ON ti.item_id = c.comment_iid \
    INNER JOIN category_item_ref AS tcir ON ti.item_id = tcir.category_item_ref_iid \
    GROUP BY ti.item_id

sql_attr_uint = sold
sql_attr_uint = rating
sql_attr_uint = comments
sql_attr_uint = warranty
sql_attr_bigint = iid
sql_attr_bigint = nick
sql_attr_bigint = price
sql_attr_bigint = popular
sql_attr_multi = uint tids from field;
```

Поиск через Sphinx работает быстрее, но так как много атрибутов, в частности присутствует sql_attr_multi  tids, что тормозит, почему то поиск и сортировку. Время выборки 600 тысяч товаров, составляет около 18~19 секунд. Пробовали привязывать товары только к одной категории, то есть атрибут tids у нас стал sql_attr_uint. Время выборки уменьшилось, до 3~5 секунд, что тоже не сильно хорошо.

Подскажете, что я делаю не так, возможно стоит, как то по-другому построить индекс для sphinx, потому что мне кажется, он должен работать быстрее. Возможно, как то нужно по-другому построить структуру таблиц, или использовать другую платформу для базы данных, например MySQL, MongoDB, PostgreSQL, MariaDB.

Comment: А зачем в таблице с товарами вмешалась данные о продавцах и его рейтинге (продавца, не товара)? это как минимум можно вынести в отдельную таблицу (вряд ли у каждого товара свой личный продавец).

ссылка на файл недоступна. Верните назад текст.

Comment: Ну что бы можно было найти товар по нику и рейтингу продавца. Вынести можно, спс за идею.

Comment: в колонке ников продавцов есть же дубликаты? и рейтинг то привязан к продавцу? Тогда, если рейтинг продавца поменялся, что, всю таблицу шерстить?

Зачем Вы убираете структуру таблицы или портите ее отображение?

Comment: Отредактировал, убрал лишнее.

Comment: Если Вы выбираете 600000 записей за раз, то возникает вопрос зачем? Кроме того, я не вижу у Вас сортировки. Т.е. достаточно выгрести в любом порядке?
Кроме того я не очень понимаю, зачем делать join комментариев чтобы потом сделать опять group by?

Comment: И если можно, скопируйте прямо сюда описание таблиц - людям будет проще. И добавьте тег sphinx сюда - чем плодить вопросы не понятно зачем (по крайней мере, пока не определили, в чём проблеме), лучше сделать один хороший

Comment: 600000 это не все записи которые я выбираю за раз, а общее количество найденных результатов для запроса, а выбираю я только LIMIT'том для организации пагинации. 
Необходимо сортировка(по полям item_sold, item_rating, item_popular, item_price) и фильтрация(по полям item_warranty item_price). 
Описание таблиц прилагал - http://clip2net.com/s/5OTUA3.

Comment: Значит для начала надо добавить индексы на поля item_sold, item_rating, item_popular, item_price, item_warranty и item_price. Или уже есть?

Comment: Индексы не помогут вроде бы в сортировке.

Answer (score 1):

Итак, судя по всему, у SQL-сервера сейчас две проблемы, съедающих ресурсы - отфильтровать 600000 записей и отсортировать их. Причём, судя по схожему топику ([MySQL performance: sort is slow in large table, even though filtered subset is small](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14851399/mysql-performance-sort-is-slow-in-large-table-even-though-filtered-subset-is-s)) вторую проблему индексы не решат.

Поэтому предлагаю идею, как убить сразу двух зайцев. Надо научиться примерно предсказывать значение величины, по которой происходит сортировка, в конечной маленькой выборке с учётом сортировки. Т.е., допустим, надо отфильтровать по `item_warranty=X` (получится 600000 записей), отсортировать по `item_sold` и выбрать записи с 1001-й по 2000-ю. Вот и надо как-то посчитать или сохранить с предыдущего запуска для `item_warranty=X Y`, такой что `item_sold>Y` для первых 2000 записей. Можно с большим запасом. Т.е. фишка в том, что можно одним запросом эффективно (с использованием индексов) отсечь большинство записей: `where item_warranty=X and item_sold>Y`. Пусть этот запрос выдаст 2500 записей. Их отсортировать и выбрать с 1001-й по 2000-ю - гораздо более простая задача для сервера.